# How do you compose _Just with the at lens

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm not able to figure out how to compose nicely access to a `Data.Map` with a lens accessing a record. Say that I have:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.TH
import Data.Map

data Person =
  Person
    { _age :: Int
    , _name :: String
    }
  deriving (Show)

makeLenses ''Person

database = fromList [(1, Person 35 "John")]
```

What would be the one liner that allows getting John's age? Because

```
johsnAge = database ^. at 1 . _Just . age
```

Is giving me error:

```
    • No instance for (Monoid Int) arising from a use of ‘_Just’
    • In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘_Just’
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘_Just . age’
      In the second argument of ‘(^.)’, namely ‘at 1 . _Just . age’
   |
18 | johsnAge = database ^. at 1 . _Just . age
   |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make it this:

```
johsnAge = database ^? at 1 . _Just . age
```

Or for more brevity,

```
johnsAge = database ^? ix 1 . age
```

The problem is that there is no guarantee that the `database` table will contain the value requested, so both of these expressions are of type `Traversal' (Map Int Person) Int`. So in this case `johnsAge :: Maybe Int`.

If you use `^.` to access a Traversal and the final value (in this case `age`) is a Monoid then you get the zero value, and if there are multiple hits (not possible for a `Map`) then you get their concatenation. However in this case its not a monoid, so you get a type error instead.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `^?` and `ix` instead?

```
*Q65578938> database ^? ix 1 . age
Just 35
*Q65578938> database ^? ix 2 . age
Nothing
```